# how to assign label value to textbox in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have tried this:

```
var fun(lblConversionFactor, txtConversionFactor)
{
    var lblConversionFactor1 = document.getElementById(lblConversionFactor).valueOf();
    var txtConversionFactor1 = document.getElementById(txtConversionFactor).valueOf();
    txtConversionFactor1 = lblConversionFactor1;
}
```

tell me , if you know solution?

Comment: You are not assigning it to the textbox. Read your code out loud. What is `txtConversionFactor1`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [ask] before asking your next question.  I believe the question you were asking could have been very simple and had an immediate answer, but your question was poorly written - it didn't include enough code to let us reproduce your issue, and you didn't clearly state how your code was failing.  We're here to help, but we work best when the questions are complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** complete rewrite, after making my own [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gQLUQ/1/).

Try this:

#### HTML

```
<label id="fah">&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" id="feh" />
<button id="T2L">Text to label</button>
<button id="L2T">Label to text</button>
```

#### JS

```
function textboxToLabel(lblConversionFactor, txtConversionFactor) {
    document.getElementById(lblConversionFactor).innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById(txtConversionFactor).value;
}

function labelToText(lblConversionFactor, txtConversionFactor) {
    document.getElementById(txtConversionFactor).value = 
        document.getElementById(lblConversionFactor).innerHTML;
}

document.getElementById("T2L").addEventListener("click", function() {
    textboxToLabel("fah", "feh");
});

document.getElementById("L2T").addEventListener("click", function() {
    labelToText("fah", "feh");
});
```

First, I provided my own HTML code, since you didn't provide us with any.  Questions are a lot easier to answer when we have more information to work with.

I've included ways to set a label from a text box and to set a textbox from a label.  Note that in dealing with labels, I get the `.innerHTML` of the element, while with textboxes, I use the `.value`.

The third line of code you use won't produce any visual effect - it's simply setting the local variables rather than the DOM elements.  To set the DOM element, you have to use the reference directly, as in my example.